reduce or remove salt and pepper or noise from manga text segmentation
is there any algorithm that can reduce remove salt and pepper or noise without damaging the text segmentation on this case like using Morphological , blur method or fastNlMeansDenoising?
for example the Morphological opening use kernel 3x3 or 5x5 still got bad result because the size of noise is various, i can't filter the image with a lot of filter layers that can cause problem for performance and time consuming program also it need lot of resource

i have been use lot of algorithm that can remove salt and pepper or noise but still got bad result because the text segmentation also being reduce
i expect that some algorithm can reduce this salt and pepper or noise from this image without much of filter layers

Can you post the original image?

[mre] required. also tag your language.

There’s no salt and pepper noise in that image. It’s a binary image, some objects are really small and can be removed by an area opening (select on area). But lots of the non-text objects should be distinguished by not looking like text, which the text transcription code should be able to do.
